# Can the LIKE statement be optimized to not do full table scans?

Tags: sqlite, query-optimization, sql-like

I want to get a subtree from a table by tree path.

the `path` column stores strings like:

```
foo/
foo/bar/
foo/bar/baz/
```

If I try to select all records that start with a certain path:

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM f WHERE path LIKE "foo/%"
```

it tells me that the table is scanned, even though the `path` column is indexed :(

Is there any way I could make LIKE use the index and not scan the table?

I found a way to achieve what I want with closure table, but it's harder to maintain and writes are extremely slow...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to use an index for LIKE in SQLite,

1. the table column must have TEXT [affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity), i.e., have a type of TEXT or VARCHAR or something like that; and
2. the index must be declared as COLLATE NOCASE (either directly, or because the column has been declared as COLLATE NOCASE):

   ```
   > CREATE TABLE f(path TEXT);
   > CREATE INDEX fi ON f(path COLLATE NOCASE);
   > EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM f WHERE path LIKE 'foo/%';
   0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE f USING COVERING INDEX fi (path>? AND path<?)
   ```

The second restriction could be removed with the [case_sensitive_like PRAGMA](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_case_sensitive_like), but this would change the behaviour of LIKE.
Alternatively, one could use a case-sensitive comparison, by replacing `LIKE 'foo/%'` with `GLOB 'foo/*'`.

Answer (score 3):

`LIKE` has strict requirements to be optimizable with an index [(ref)](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html).

If you can relax your requirements a little, you can use lexicographic ordering to get indexed lookups, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM f WHERE PATH >= 'foo/' AND PATH < 'foo0'
```

where `0` is the lexigographically next character after `/`.

This is essentially the same optimization the optimizer would do for `LIKE`s if the requirements for optimization are met.

Comment: I was reading that same page but had a different conclusion. In chapter 4 it states it can optimize under very strict rules.

Comment: Thanks this one uses search :) Query looks kind of weird though